# Struggle to pull email with reminder message on date count down

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried over and over to get this 'simple' script to work. I would like to scan over a column of dates and if a pre set 'days due' is today, it will then pull the email from the same row with a reminder message stating the task is due. For whatever reason, when I do this I cannot get multiple emails to fire to different owners and my loop keeps stacking the tasks due on the same day. I can [SHARE SHEET HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Zeg6oIqhecJZ7NnNhZE62juQ6cnjFrQyZsIljZu0fI/edit?usp=sharing). any help is appreciated!!

```
function checkReminder() {
// get the spreadsheet object
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// set the first sheet as active
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
// fetch this sheet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

// figure out what the last row is
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
// is the headers, so start with row 2
var startRow = 2;

// grab column 5 (the 'days left' column) 
var range = sheet.getRange(2,5,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var days_left_values = range.getValues();

// Now, grab the reminder name column
range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

//Range A2:End of rows and columns
data = sheet.getRange(2, 6, lastRow-startRow+1,1);

//Now, grab the emails
var email_values = data.getValues();
//Logger.log(email_values)
//Logger.log(reminder_info_values)
//=======================Above this line works 
fine====================================

for (k in email_values){
var row = email_values[k];}
//var emailAddress =row[5]

var warning_count = 0;
var msg = "";

// Loop over the days left values
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
if(days_left == 7) {
  // if it's exactly 7, do something with the data.
  var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];
  var emailAddress = row[6]
  msg = msg + "Reminder: "+reminder_name+" is due in "+days_left+"  
  days.\n";

} 
}


  warning_count++;



if(warning_count) {
//MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, 
   //"Reminder Spreadsheet Message", msg);
Logger.log(emailAddress);
Logger.log(msg);
}

}
```

Comment: The linked spreadsheet isn't publicly available. It's not clear what you mean by " i cannot get multiple emails to fire to different owners"

Comment: My first impression is that your code is overly complicated.  Give us access to the data and perhaps we can suggest an alternate course.

Comment: I have updated the link share profile to 'anyone with the link' to access. Please let me know if it isn't working, I very much appreciate the input on this project!